# Iterated integral of $x/(1+y^3)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_0^{10}\int_x^{10}\frac{x}{1+y^3}dydx$$

I assume there's a neat substitution but I can't see one. Using Fubini's theorem doesn't seem to be much help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: switch the order : $I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{10} \int_{0}^y \dfrac{x}{1+y^3}dxdy$, then integrate with respect to $x$ first, and then use a substitution $u = y^3$ to finish it off...

Comment: That clears it up. My error was not switching the limits when I switched the order. Thanks!

Comment: thank you, Sopia. Are you a math major in the states?

Comment: I am a math major, but in Canada actually